# When I write simple server, and want to provide static webiste, why don't I have to use utf-8 encoding as it is in the example below?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is the same outcome when I provide the utf-8 encoding and the same when I leave it out?

```
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    if (req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
            res.end(data)
        })
    }
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Listening on port ', PORT))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the encoding, then you get a raw buffer instead of a string. (See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)).

The [end method](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) can be passed either a raw buffer or a string.

Comment: Yep, but when I load the side, it is the same with and without utf-8. Doesn't the browser need that, or?

Comment: Nothing about the way you invoke `readFile` has any effect on what Content-Type header is sent to the browser.